# Executing offline bundle fails after update to React Native 0.7.1

Tags: ios, react-native

I recently updated React Native to v0.7.1 using `npm` as well as to `iojs` using homebrew. However, when executing the application in the offline version (after downloading the bundle using `curl`) I receive the following error:

```
2015-07-16 18:19:21.937 [error][tid:com.facebook.React.JavaScript] "Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this._localModuleNameToMethodIDToName[r][t]')
     stack: 
      _callFunction   main.jsbundle:3
      <unknown>       main.jsbundle:3
      <unknown>       main.jsbundle:3
      perform         main.jsbundle:2
      batchedUpdates  main.jsbundle:5
      u               main.jsbundle:2
      <unknown>       main.jsbundle:3
      T               main.jsbundle:3
      C               main.jsbundle:3
      processBatch    main.jsbundle:3
     URL: file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/BBE9CDDD-159D-4269-A649-B76CCD11737E/hafnertecBluetoothControlReactNative.app/main.jsbundle
     line: 3
     message: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this._localModuleNameToMethodIDToName[r][t]')"
```

The development version works fine. I started this project with React Native v0.4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been caused by the module `react-native-localization` which has required an old version of `react-native`. [This issue has already been fixed.](https://github.com/stefalda/ReactNativeLocalization/issues/4)